# React Component Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

```
import React from 'react';

const InputBoxes = ({
  userClick = ''
  , name = ''
  , class_name = ''
  , style = ''})=> (
  <div
    className={class_name.divContainer}
    style={style.divContainer}>
      <form className={class_name.formContainer}
      style={style.formContainer} >
        <input type='text' name={name.userName}
        className={class_name.userName}
        style={style.userName} />

        <input type='text' name={name.userPass}
        className={class_name.userPass}
        style={style.userPass} />

        <button name={name.clientButton}
        className={class_name.clientButton}
        style={style.clientButton}
        onClick={userClick.clientButton}></button>
      </form>

  </div>

);


export default InputBoxes;
```

my other file is this simple, I hoped but won't work can you guys help me out am i doing something wrong here? 
I should render on div container divClass on dom but does not....

```
import React from 'react';
import reactDOM from 'react-dom';
import InputBoxes from './components/input_boxes';

reactDOM.render(
  <InputBoxes
    className={class_name.divContainer = 'divClass'} />
  ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information - is this throwing any helpful errors?

Comment: @Fallen3000, Can you explain this code `<InputBoxes
    className={class_name.divContainer = 'divClass'} />` ?

Comment: no it wasn't throwing errors it just wouldn't show on the DOM

Comment: thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function argument is `class_name` then you shouldn't use `className`, you should do

```
<InputBoxes class_name={{divContainer: 'divClass'}} />
```

Generally underscore notation isn't common in JS code. I'd recommend sticking with established conventions to avoid confusion.